# Where is the light on the Pip-Boy 3000A?

Tags: pc, fallout-3

The text during the loading screens talk about a light on the Pip-Boy, and tell you that having it turned on decreases your ability to sneak.

Where is this light located, and how to turn it on/off.

*(Note that I couldn't find anything in the control settings)*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hold down the Pip-Boy/Menu button. By default, that's '**Tab**'.